# OCaml function syntax error

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

The following code gives an error:

```
let alpha = Hashtbl.create 26 in
let print_and_add a =
    print_char a;
    Hashtbl.add alpha a true;;
let str = read_line () in
String.iter (fun x -> if Hashtbl.mem alpha x=false then print_and_add x) str
```

What it's supposed to do:each time the function is called (with a char argument),it should print the char,and add it to the Hash table (alpha).
I tried using the other syntax for functions:

```
let alpha = Hashtbl.create 26 in
let print_and_add = (fun a ->
    print_char a;
    Hashtbl.add alpha a true) in
let str = read_line () in
String.iter (fun x -> if Hashtbl.mem alpha x=false then print_and_add x) str
```

But I still want to know why the first code fails.
-Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The `;;` symbol specifically marks the end of an expression at the global level. So everything after it has to be part of a different expression. Hence `alpha` can't be defined after that.

I never use `;;` in source code, only when typing to the toplevel. In my opinion, that's what it's for.

Your code also has `let print_and_add ...` without a corresponding `in`. This is valid only at the global level (not inside an expression).

If you change `;;` to `in` in your original code, you get something that works. At least it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`alpha` is no longer in scope when you attempt to use it the second time in the first snippet.

Comment: Thanks,but why is it in the scope in the second code snippet?I don't see a big difference between the two.

Comment: `let ... in ...` only binds the definitions locally: hence "in". despite your indentation, the the former case, you're ending the statement after defining print_and_add.

Comment: And indentation is syntactically irrelevant.